# Is $|x| \cdot |x| = |x^2| = x^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

> Is $|x| \cdot |x| = |x^2| = x^2$ ?

I'm very sorry if this question is a duplicate but I couldn't find anything about it (most likely because it's wrong..). But I'm not sure if this is correct so I need to ask you.

$$|x| \cdot |x| = |x^2| \text{ should be alright}$$

Now my confusion starts. $x^2$ should be positive / neutral for any value. That would mean we can ignore the absolute value sign? On the other hand we could have that $|-x^2|$. But that would be a different thing than $|x^2|$, they are not equal to each other...? Please help me if I do this little thing wrong the entire task will be wrong. I got some thinking error here..

When there is the same question (I couldn't find one), please link me to it and I will delete this one immediately.

Comment: For real numbers, yes $|x|^2=x^2$.  As for a proof, consider the two cases separately, $x\geq 0$ and $x<0$.  In the case of $x\geq 0$ you may replace each occurrence of $|x|$ with $x$ as they are equal by definition in that case.  In the case of $x<0$ you may replace each occurrence of $|x|$ with $-x$ as they are equal by definition in that case.  In either case the above simplifies as desired.  Note however that this fails for arbitrary *complex* numbers.  For example $|i|\cdot |i|=|i^2|=1\neq -1=i^2$

Comment: If the question is really about $|-x^2|$ versus $|x^2|$, maybe the title could reflect that? I think it's good to question these things, but it's a bit hard to tell what it is you're unsure about.

Comment: For real numbers, yes. It is a direct result of the proposition $x^2 \ge 0$. But it's not true for odd powers.  And it's not true for necessarily of systems other than real numbers.  The simplest counter example is probably the complex numbers that allow of for numbers such as $i$ where $i^2 = - 1 \not \ge 0$ and where $x^2 \not \ge 0$ in general.

Comment: Important to note $-(x^2) \ne (-x)^2$.  When we write $-x^2$ we mean $-(x^2)$.    I think a single example with make this clear $-3^2 = -(3^2) = -(3*3) = - 9$ but $(-3)^2 = (-3)*(-3) = 9$.  Absolute values show $|(-3)| *|(-3)| = |(-3)^2| = (-3)^2$ but $|-3|*|3| = |-(3)*(3)| = |-(3)^2| = |-3^2| = 3^2 \ne - 3^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are thinking it too hard. You could just look at the **definition** of the absolute value
$$
|x|:=\begin{cases}
x,&x\geq 0\\
-x,&x<0
\end{cases}
$$
and check on your own that $|x|^2=|x^2|=x^2$.

---

In general, we have  $|a|\cdot|b|=|ab|$, which is true also for complex numbers; but the identity $|x^2|=x^2$ is not necessarily true in the complex world.

Answer (score 3):

For real numbers, this is true. We have:

$$|x| = sgn(x) \cdot x$$

And thus:

$$|x| \cdot |x| = sgn(x)^2 \cdot x^2 = x^2$$

Also:

$$|x^2| = sgn(x^2) \cdot x^2 = x^2$$

Answer (score 3):

I think the confusion is coming from the fact that $|-a| = |a|$ is a perfectly valid statement. Absolute values, in a way, ignore the sign of a number. Also, you can ignore the absolute values signs in $|a|$ when you know that $a$ is always nonnegative. Thus
$$ |x|^2 = |x| \cdot |x| = |x \cdot x| = |x^2| = x^2 $$
which could be seen in a variety of other ways.

P.S.: Don't feel bad about posting a possible duplicate question! It can be hard finding your question online, and so long as you tried to search for it, having your post flagged as a duplicate is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is "yes". Since, as you point out, $x^2 \ge 0$, it is its own absolute value and you can "ignore the absolute value signs".

If  $x \ne 0$ then $-x^2$ is negative, Its absolute value is $x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

I think your confusion is confusing $-x^2 $ which is $-(x^2)$ which is always negative (or zero) and is *not* a square number.  With $(-x)^2$ which *is* a square number and therefor always positive (or zero).

$-x^2 \ne (-x)^2$  (Unless $x = 0$).

Oh, and I guess you confusion is also $|-a| = |a|$.  The absolute value of a negative value is *not* a different thing than an absolute value of a positive value.  Indeed, the absolute value of a negative value is **ALWAYS** the *exact* same thing as the absolute value of the corresponding positive value. That is the entire point of absolute values.

So $|-5| = |5| = 5$ and $|-x^2| = |x^2| = x^2$.

And, for the record $|-x|*|-x| = |(-x)^2| = (-x)^2 = x^2$.  While $|x|*|x| = |x^2| = x^2$ and **ALWAYS** $|-x| = |x|$.  Always.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: Look at the graph $y = x^2$; does $y$ ever submerge below the $y$-axis? That should give you an idea for all real numbers.

However, you have $a*i$ where $a$ is a real constant, and $i$ is an imaginary number. Squaring it gives $$(ai)^2 = a^2i^2 = a^2(-1) = -a^2$$ Therefore, if an imaginary number is squared, there is no positive solution.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$|x|\cdot |x|=|x|^2=x^2$$